# HQL : filtering query only 2 month before

Tags: date, hql

i want to ask, how to convert this postgres query to HQL :

select * from transactions
where **trans_time >= date(now() - 60 * interval '1 day')**

how to convert that query(in bold type) to hql?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
minDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -60);
String hql = "select t from Transaction t where t.transactionTime >= :minDate";
List<Transaction> result = session.createQuery(hql)
                                  .setTimestamp("minDate", cal.getTime())
                                  .list();
```