# Older then query in java persistence

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, hql

I need to do a query where i take things older then 5 days.(a custom date)
i have looked at HQL but since it is in persistence i dont have access to setTimestamp as per [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10780471/hql-filtering-query-only-2-month-before)

```
String hqlQuery;
Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
minDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -days);
hqlQuery = "select n from notifications where n.app_id=:app and ((n.sent_date<=:minDate) OR (n.sent_date is null)) and n.handled='N'";
```

is how i tried...
Any sweet helpers, thanks in advance :-)

Edit:
So i changed my method it now looks like this:

```
public static List<Notification> findOlderThen(EntityManager em, Long app, int days) {
    String hqlQuery;
    Calendar minDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    minDate.add(Calendar.DATE, -days);
    hqlQuery = "select n from notifications where n.app_id=:app and ((n.sent_date<=:minDate) OR (n.sent_date is null)) and n.handled='N'";
    System.out.println(hqlQuery);
    return em.createQuery(hqlQuery).setParameter("app", app).setParameter("minDate",minDate.getTime()).getResultList();
}
```

But it gives this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing the query [select n from notifications where n.app_id=:app and ((n.sent_date<=:minDate) OR (n.sent_date is null)) and n.handled='N'], line 1, column 28: syntax error at [where].
Internal Exception: UnwantedTokenException(found=where, expected 80)
```

Comment: so.... you get an exception when you try this?

Comment: Can't try it, can't add the date to the query, at least don't know how.

Comment: you need to declare an alias. `select n from notifications n where...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SessionFactory sf = // get your session factory
Query q = sf.getCurrentSession()
        .createQuery(hqlQuery);
q.setParameter("minDate",minDate.getTime())
 .setParameter("app", appId)
 .list();
```

Would be how you set a date parameter, assuming type of sent_date is Date in Notifications model class. Also, on this part of your query `select n from notifications`, make sure notifications is the actual name of your class. Case matters! It should probably be `select n from Notifications n`.

**Update:**

You need to declare the alias for the class.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, aren't you supposed to do something like this when you're adding dates in a query:

```
hqlQuery = "select n from notifications where n.app_id=:app and ((n.sent_date<=':minDate') OR (n.sent_date is null)) and n.handled='N'";
```

notice the ' around the minDate variable

Comment: you shouldn't have to do that, hibernate should automatically recognize that sent_date is a Date and escape the value for you.